# MySQL subquery not working (bad logical)

Tags: mysql, subquery

Please, can you review this query? I can't retrive the correct values with the subquery. I believe my logic is incorrect.

I'm trying to make this work day after day, but without succcess.

Above the SQL query in the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad7b2/8) has the comments to reproduce the error.

With this [sketch](http://sencial.me/images/esquema_sql_preco.gif) you can have a better understanding of what I need.

```
SELECT P.nome, centroide_produto_id, similar_produto_id, 

(SELECT preco_venda FROM precos A
WHERE A.produto_id=CL.similar_produto_id 

AND A.preco_id = (
SELECT Max(preco_id) FROM precos A2, cluster_copy3 CL2 WHERE A2.produto_id=A.produto_id AND A2.produto_id=CL2.similar_produto_id
AND A2.preco_venda = (SELECT Max(preco_venda) FROM precos A3, cluster_copy3 CL3 WHERE A3.produto_id=CL3.similar_produto_id AND CL3.centroide_produto_id=CL.centroide_produto_id)
)

) AS preco_maximo

FROM produtos P, cluster_copy3 CL
WHERE P.produto_id=CL.centroide_produto_id 
AND CL.centroide_produto_id IN (9817, 9816)

#GROUP BY CL.centroide_produto_id
```

Comment: It would help if we knew what you were trying to do.  Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Comment: Hi Gordon! The desired values are explained at sqlfiddle, once here I cannot show the table rows.

Comment: Somebody please? With [this](http://sencial.me/images/esquema_sql_preco.gif) sketch you can have a better understanding of what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listing your expected results would help. If you are truly looking for max(preco_id) and max(preco_venda), then it might be something like this:

```
SELECT p.nome, c.centroide_produto_id, c.similar_produto_id
      ,x.max_preco_id
      ,x.preco_maximo
  FROM produtos p
  JOIN cluster_copy3 c ON (p.produto_id = c.centroide_produto_id AND
                           c.centroide_produto_id IN (9817, 9816)
                          )
  JOIN (SELECT produto_id
              ,MAX(preco_id) max_preco_id
              ,MAX(preco_venda) preco_maximo
          FROM precos
          GROUP BY produto_id) x ON (x.produto_id = p.produto_id)
```

Output:

```
|                                           nome | centroide_produto_id | similar_produto_id | max_preco_id | preco_maximo |
|------------------------------------------------|----------------------|--------------------|--------------|--------------|
|                        My NY EDT Feminino 30ml |                 9816 |               9816 |        31438 |          169 |
|                        My NY EDT Feminino 30ml |                 9816 |               9819 |        31438 |          169 |
| Flower By Kenzo EDP Recarregável Feminino 30ml |                 9817 |               9817 |        31455 |          149 |
| Flower By Kenzo EDP Recarregável Feminino 30ml |                 9817 |               9830 |        31455 |          149 |
```

If you are looking for max(preco_venda) and the associated preco_id, then perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT p.nome, c.centroide_produto_id, c.similar_produto_id
      ,y.preco_id
      ,y.preco_maximo
  FROM produtos p
  JOIN cluster_copy3 c ON (p.produto_id = c.centroide_produto_id AND
                           c.centroide_produto_id IN (9817, 9816)
                          )
  JOIN (

SELECT x.produto_id, x.preco_maximo, MAX(p.preco_id) preco_id
  FROM precos p
  JOIN (SELECT produto_id
              ,MAX(preco_venda) preco_maximo
          FROM precos
          GROUP BY produto_id
        ) x ON (x.produto_id = p.produto_id AND
                x.preco_maximo = p.preco_venda)
  GROUP BY x.produto_id, x.preco_maximo

    ) y ON (y.produto_id = p.produto_id)
```

Output:

```
|                                           nome | centroide_produto_id | similar_produto_id | preco_id | preco_maximo |
|------------------------------------------------|----------------------|--------------------|----------|--------------|
|                        My NY EDT Feminino 30ml |                 9816 |               9816 |    31438 |          169 |
|                        My NY EDT Feminino 30ml |                 9816 |               9819 |    31438 |          169 |
| Flower By Kenzo EDP Recarregável Feminino 30ml |                 9817 |               9817 |    31455 |          149 |
| Flower By Kenzo EDP Recarregável Feminino 30ml |                 9817 |               9830 |    31455 |          149 |
```

Although the output is the same, the it is not the max id of the cluster being returned, but the id associated with the max preco.

**Update 1:**

Again, I'm guessing at what you are looking for. It looks like you want only two rows in the result. For each product of interest, find the most recent price of all its related products (as defined in precos), and then take the maximum price of these most recent prices:

```
SELECT x.nome, x.centroide_produto_id, MAX(p2.preco_venda) AS venda_maximo
  FROM (SELECT p.nome, c.centroide_produto_id, c.similar_produto_id, MAX(pr.preco_id) AS max_preco_id
          FROM produtos p
          JOIN cluster_copy3 c ON (p.produto_id = c.centroide_produto_id)
          JOIN precos pr ON (pr.produto_id = c.similar_produto_id)
          WHERE p.produto_id IN (9817, 9816)
          GROUP BY p.nome, c.centroide_produto_id, c.similar_produto_id
       ) x
   JOIN precos p2 ON (p2.preco_id = x.max_preco_id)
   GROUP BY x.nome, x.centroide_produto_id
   ORDER BY x.centroide_produto_id
```

Output:

```
|                                           nome | centroide_produto_id | venda_maximo |
|------------------------------------------------|----------------------|--------------|
|                        My NY EDT Feminino 30ml |                 9816 |          243 |
| Flower By Kenzo EDP Recarregável Feminino 30ml |                 9817 |          149 |
```

Comment: Hi Glenn! Thank you for your suggestion, but the prices returned are not correct. Please see this [sketch][2] that you can have a better understanding of what I need.

Comment: @Ailton Many people would be happy to help, but it is still very difficult to understand what it is you wish to see. I looked at your diagram and I can see you are looking for "most recent" rather than "max", but I am still not clear on the desired final output.  Add to your question a table, somewhat in the format of the output in my answer showing exactly the rows and columns you expect to see returned from your query. Do you want to see these 4 rows with these 4 columns?  What value do you expect in each position.  Then your diagram might help in explaining the why.

Comment: Hi Glenn! Please see this new [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad7b2/9) with this new [sketch](http://sencial.me/images/esquema_sql_preco.gif)

Comment: Thank you very much Glenn! That is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

preco_maximo = null is your problem ?
Adding this condition should resolve this

```
AND CL.similar_produto_id != CL.centroide_produto_id
```

Comment: Hi! No, the null value is expected once I need only 1 value per centroide_produto_id. The problem is the preco_maximo 299 is incorrect because I need the max(preco_id) - 31490 or 31455 WITH the max(preco_venda) which is 149 to the centroide_produto_id 9817